# Data not available after restart mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a DB dump which has been exported from PHPMyAdmin and I sourced it using the terminal to MySQL. 
**source file/path/file.sql**

All tables and data created but after exit and enter again to MySQL console, the MySQL all the data has been lost only the table structure is there.

**exit**

**mysql -u user -p**

I’ve tried on several times but same happened then I completely uninstalled and install MySQL again, but the result was same.

What may be the reason for this? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the data was actually successfully imported (e.g. it was there before the restart)?

Comment: Even if this might not be connected to programming after all: you should share more details about what you've did to "source" the data into MySQL, explain how you checked for the success, and how you restarted the system

Comment: smells like missing `commit`....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Commit; Statement can help you.

But please help us first by showing us some code. Then we maybe able to help you more efficiently.

See link for more Information on Commit:
https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/tcl-command.php

To give you the essential points from the link:
COMMIT command is used to permanently save any transaction into the database.

When we use any DML command like INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE, the changes made by these commands are not permanent, until the current session is closed, the changes made by these commands can be rolled back.

To avoid that, we use the COMMIT command to mark the changes as permanent.

The code is realy simple, make all you changes and then use:

```
Commit;
```

Thats all. Just remember that you can rollback at a maximum 1 commit ;)
-> So changes become permanent after the second "Commit"